# Поиск неподстроки

Tags: алгоритм, строки

Дан текст/строка/набор байт. Требуется найти такую строку, которая не является подстрокой этого текста. "Неподстрока" не должна быть слишком длинной, алгоритм поиска не должен быть слишком накладным.

Зачем это нужно? Скажем у вас есть текст, вы хотите вставить его [heredoc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81). Вам нужны ограничители, которых вы не встретите в тексте.

Или вы хотите поменять в тексте символы местами с помощью `replace`. `text.replace('a', 'b').replace('b', 'a')` работать не будет. Нужно `text.replace('a', T).replace('b', 'a').replace(T, 'b')`, где `T` не встречается в исходном тексте, иначе будет плохо. (*к `T` есть дополнительные требования, их пока опустим*).

Или с помощью "неподстроки" можно вносить в текст разметку, которую затем можно удалить восстановив исходный текст. Применений много.

Comment: сгенерируйте GUID/UUID, бытует мнение, что этого достаточно, чтобы даже при последовательных генерациях коллизию не найти, не говоря уже про произвольный текст.

Comment: Например: Определите начало названия неподстроки, пусть будет **#=SV=#** ищите в тексте подстроку, если нашли поменяли на **#=S_V=#** и проверяете. Либо можно пробовать генерить случайную строку N длины и проверять ее на вхождение

Comment: В качестве бреда, делаем частотный анализ текста(достаточно стадии подсчета кол-ва каждого из символов), находим самый редкий символ и делаем неподстроку длинной в кол-во этого символа +1 :)

Comment: В порядке бреда... Смотрим символ, которого вообще нет в тексте. Нашли - вот он и будет... Не нашли? берем его и смотрим, какие символы могут быть за ним в тексте (опять в поисках символа, которого нет). Нашли? Отлично, вот она, пара... Не нашли? Какая пара была самая редкая? ищем третий символ в дополнение к ней.... и т.д. Еще один вариант - esc-символ, который говорит о том, что за ним идет нечто служебное. В его качестве можно взять наиболее редко используемый, чтоб удваивать пришлось пореже.

Comment: Какой размер символа текста? Байт, utf8 или что-то еще? И еще. "Неподстрока" должна содержать только символы данного текста?

Comment: @avp, все варианты возможны. Не подстрока строки из целых чисел, не подстрока в UTF8, не подстрока в байтах (в однобайтовой кодировке). Если научиться в байтах, то из неё строится всё остальное.

Comment: imho @ВладимирКлыков уже  предложил очень хороший вариант. Берем самый редко встречаемый символ и удваивая-утраивая-и-т-д его делаем искомую подстроку.

Comment: Я бы пробовал последовательности начиная от одного символа/байта и пока не будет найдена искомая. Генерим множество всех сочетаний выбранной длины из набора символов. Идём по тексту или что у нас там и удаляем из этого множества найденные там сочетания. Если что-то осталось в множестве после прохода по тексту - вот вам ваши "неподстроки". Если ничего не осталось - пробуем с большей длиной. Скорее всего на длине 2 или 3 уже найдётся какое-то уникальное сочетание, если, конечно, текст специально "зловредно" не составлен из всех возможных сочетаний букв.

Answer (score 2):

Простой случай - когда в строке задействованы не все символы из доступного набора, тогда берём не встречающийся в строке символ.

Иначе строим суффиксный массив. Это массив номеров, под которыми идут суффиксы в лексикографическом порядке. Например, для строки "ababab" суффиксы

```
       pos   order
ababab  0      2 
 babab  1      5 
  abab  2      1
   bab  3      4
    ab  4      0
     b  5      3
```

Считаем длины наибольших общих префиксов соседних (по номерам в массиве) суффиксов - LCP,  longest common prefix - например, с помощью алгоритма Касаи.

```
       pos   order   lcp
    ab  4      0     
  abab  2      1      2 
ababab  0      2      4 
     b  5      3      0 
   bab  3      4      1 
 babab  1      5      3
```

Выбираем пару соседних суффиксов с небольшим значением LCP[i] и строим строку между ними `ababab, b => "aa"`

Не исключаю, что возможен тонкий момент - добавленная уникальная строка при замене чего-то там породит такую же с наложением, но навскидку примера я не сочинил.

Answer (score 0):

Для текста или строки наименее характерным будет многократное повторение символа. Поэтому нужно сделать небольшую последовательность повторяющихся символов и проверить текст на наличие такой последовательности. Если нашлась, то добавить символы или изменить символ. Если не с первой попытки, то очень быстро искомая уникальная последовательность будет найдена. Для массива байтов может понадобиться чуть больше попыток. Помимо повторяющихся символов можно использовать упорядоченные последовательности.